# How to use jQuery together with Velocityjs in a Vite(Typescript) project

Tags: jquery, vite, velocity.js

in my Vite project I want to use jQuery combined with Velocityjs, but i'm not sure how to import everything so the common syntax `$("body").velocity({ opacity: 0.5 });` works.

at the moment I have only imported the main files in my main.ts

```
import $ from "jquery";
import Velocity from "velocity-animate";
```